# Mono 2.8.1 assertion mono_wsq_count (wsq) == 0

Tags: c#, c, linux, multithreading, mono

we are currently having serious problems running a pure c# application on mono 2.8.1 on debian 5.

We are using .net webservices as well as async sockets and probably found a race condition in the mono threadpool.

I would be thankful for every idea.

if someone has informations if mono 2.8.1 has known problems on debian 4/5 that might have something to do with this, please answer too:)

```
Assertion at mono-wsq.c:73, condition `mono_wsq_count (wsq) == 0' not met


Stacktrace:


Native stacktrace:

        mono [0x48f582]
        /lib/libpthread.so.0 [0x2abe8f8d2a80]
        /lib/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x35) [0x2abe8fb12ed5]
        /lib/libc.so.6(abort+0x183) [0x2abe8fb143f3]
        mono [0x5cd042]
        mono [0x5cd21a]
        mono [0x5f271a]
        mono [0x5924ca]
        mono [0x58c24b]
        mono [0x5bd83b]
        mono [0x5e9ed6]
        /lib/libpthread.so.0 [0x2abe8f8cafc7]
        /lib/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x2abe8fbb064d]

Debug info from gdb:


=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

Comment: Have you tried contact gonzalo AT novell DOT com? He's the one responsible for adding the assert that is being raised at your Mono installation, as you can see [here](http://repo.or.cz/w/mono.git/blobdiff/eb745dd033418198fa43c87494b8eeaa0aeffa51..97fe27bfdc88c4cd8dea73ae363702be61ee0a82:/mono/metadata/mono-wsq.c).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i allready did that:)

Comment: Can I just ask that you share any results or bug tickets that come from this issue?  I just had this assert fire for me as well.

Comment: Hey Mark, we did not find a Solution yet and the author did not yet reply. We are going to test Mono 2.6.7 to eliminate the problem.

Comment: Mark can you please discribe the Situation you received his problem? - We are still searching for answers.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this in mono 2.8.2. Someone has reported that they still see it in 2.8.2 (we don't see it in our servers any more) and we are working to debug it.

Comment: I've got it in Mono 2.10 as well. It occurred when running parallel computations in F# (compiled, not fsi) using async. I can't reproduce it in any predictable way, it just occurs sometimes.

Comment: The Final Fix(tm) will be in the upcoming 2.10.2 (it's already in the mono-2-10 and master branches). Sorry ;-)